# Vessels for frothing and pouring the milk

Tags: milk

I recently bought an espresso machine with steamer for the milk. However I noticed that the quality of the foam changes according to the vessel I use to steam and froth it.

Are there a specific type of vessel I should use for steaming, frothing and pouring the milk?

Thanks

Comment: Are you always using the same milk? Different fat percentages, preservation methods, even brands can give vastly different results.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll pay attention to the brand and type of milk to see if that's the cause

Comment: You are welcome! Even if my comment *technically* isn't a real answer. While you wait for answers, you could take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site and the Stack Exchange system in general. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar experience, and the difference seems to be due to the age of the milk. The fresher the milk, the better micro-foam I can create. Once it gets within of week of expiration, I start getting less foam.

The pitcher also makes a difference. Other people recommended the Espro toroid pitcher to me. I liked it so much, I bought two sizes: http://espro.ca/toroid/